# Why Data type in java are not object?

Tags: java, oop

I have studied about java datatype very earlier and found that they are primitive type. As java is object oriented but its data types are not. why is it so?

Comment: Why is it not defined as object or why did the designers of java have chosen primitives to be non-objects?

Comment: @amit Probably because languages before Java and that influenced the design of Java, such as C++, have it in the same way. It's perfectly possible to write a compiler that pretends that ints etc. are objects, and uses primitive types of the underlying platform behind the scenes, so that it's just as efficient as when the higher-level language would expose the primitive types in the language.

Comment: @Jesper: I was trying to understand what the OP means in "Why Data type in java are not object?" It can be interpeted as both questions - both definition [what makes them different from objects?] and both design [why did the designers have chosen to do so?]

Comment: Your terminology is very confused. Primitive types are not objects in Java, but the term 'datatype' isn't restricted to the primitive types.

Answer (score 4):

It is said that everything in Java is an Object at the same time the Java Programming Language is meant to be simple. Since the primitive data types consume less memory and can be accessed faster, they are not objects. The equivalent Wrapper classes are also available in java like "Integer" "Short" etc. They can be used as objects if you want. However, the wrapper classes will be stored in Heap and they are slow.

Answer (score 3):

It is more efficient to deal with primitive types than making each variable a full fledged object. The most common types (ie. int, char, float etc.) are simple primitives. The rest are objects.

Comment: @kundanbora - yes, but do you really think that Java would be a mainstream language if operations on primitive types were S L O W ... just to satisfy some peoples' desire of OO purity?

Comment: @StephenC java already a good language I think.But my question is, making data as primitive is efficient than object, then why we keep all other things in object. Java also provide wrapper class for primitive data type.

Comment: There are other languages that pretend as if integers etc. are objects. Behind the scenes, the compiler generates code that handles them as primitive types of the underlying platform. It isn't required that a higher-level language exposes the primitive types of the underlying platform directly. It's just a choice that the designers of the Java language made.

Comment: @Jesper - see my Answer for a response to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

It is a combination of two things.

1. It is a language design preference / choice.  The Java language designers clearly thought that primitives were different from objects ... and array types were different from classes.  They are not alone in this view.  Many other OO language designs make this kind of distinction.
2. There **is** a penalty in making primitive types such as number types full object types.

Jesper points out (in a comment on another Answer) that some languages map OO numeric types to hardware supported types under the covers.  However, he doesn't mention that this can only be made to work if you place restrictions on them.  You can only do this for a numeric type that is known to the compiler, and a leaf type; i.e. one that doesn't have (custom) subtypes.

If a numeric type is not a leaf type, then it cannot be represented as a native type because there would be no way to implement this:

```
  class MyInteger extends Integer /* a builtin numeric type */ {
      public ... add(...) { /* a different way of doing addition */ }
  }
```

Why?  Because the builtin type is represented as a native hardware integer type, and you can't do dispatching on such a representation.

In short the penalty is **either** that OO numeric (etc) types are slow and use more memory that the equivalent Java primitive types, **or** that they are ringed with restrictions that limit your ability to exploit the OO-ness of the types.

Comment: Scala is one of the languages that has types `Int`, `Long`, etc. that behave like classes but map to the JVM's `int`, `long` etc. primitives. There's a [proposal to add value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) to Scala; you could make your own classes that map to JVM primitive types. There will be restrictions on value classes, you can't do everything with them that you can do with "normal" classes.

Answer (score 2):

In Java all its Object types can be defined in terms of primitives and references to objects.

The primitive types and references are the types which cannot be defined in terms of other types.

What some languages do is hide the distinction, this effectively makes the fundamental types higher level which can make the developers life easier if they are not interested in the difference, but much harder if they are.

Few real languages are pure object orientated, pure functional or pure logic languages, you have to many some pragmatic choices to make a language usable.

Answer (score 0):

Performance and memory consumption are the good reason behind primitives data types instead of using full fledged objects.