# integers are not objects in Java, just because they are not instances of a class?

Tags: java, class, object, integer, primitive

There are already some similar questions (e.g. [Why Data type in java are not object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748882/why-data-type-in-java-are-not-object)) but I still not clear.

This is the definition of `objects` from [oracle's document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html):

> An object is a software bundle of related state and behavior.

Consider:

```
int nnn = 3;
```

I think `nnn` has the type `int`, and the state `my value is 3`, although has no behavior. Why it's not an object?

Then look at the following `iii` which is an object:

```
Integer iii = new Integer(3);
```

I found some other explanations which says "objects are instances of some class in Java". (Sorry I can't find where I read it)

So the value `nnn` is not object in Java, the most important reason is it's not an instance of some class?

So that the definition of `object` in Java should be: An object is a software bundle of related state and behavior, and in Java, it should be an instance of some class. Right?

---

Update:

Thanks for answering my question. I found I need to make this question clear since I found many people didn't notify my explanation in comments, when people commented "it's not an object because it has no behavior".

We know `Object` has some built-in methods, like `toString`, `equals`, etc. So when I define a class, say:

```
class User extends Object {
  // empty body
}
```

The instance of `User` will have these methods(behaviors) too. But what if `Object` hasn't provide all these methods? In this case, `new User()` here won't have any methods(behaviors), then we should not consider it's an object?

Sorry guys, I'm really puzzled now :(

Comment: `[...] although has no behavior. Why it's not an object?` You are answering your own question.

Comment: If `Object` has not provide built-in methods, then `class User extends Object {}` has no behavior, so that `new User` is not an object neither?

Comment: There is many differences.  Objects are allocated with `new` on the heap and referenced for a start.

Comment: `User` inherits all the behavior of `Object`.

Comment: @Freewind Object has many methods, like `user.getClass();` `user.toString()`, `user.hashCode()`, `synchronized(user)` You can't do any of those things with a primitive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yes, it has, but I said `if it has not`. Will it never be true?

Comment: Even if you do `new Serializable() { }` it still has all the methods of an object.  You can't avoid having behaviour for an Object, it is always associated with a reference, and is not inlined in other objects.

Comment: `byte[]` has all the methods of Object.

Comment: Sorry, I said what `if Object has not provide any methods`? Will `new Object()` have behaviors? (Although `Object` does have some methods now)

Comment: If it has methods, it has a behavior. That's what an object is. That's what a reference type defines. That is the difference with primitive types.

Comment: Freewind is proposing a hypothetical situation where you have a class named `Object` with no methods; would it suddenly have its own behaviors if you instantiate it. OP may be confused by the inheritance comment.

Comment: The phrase "An object is a software bundle of related state and behavior" is in a brief summary, or an overview, that introduces the rest of the lessons.  You shouldn't expect an overview like that to be specific about all the details.  That is, it's not intended to be a definition.

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Language Specification. Chapter 4. Types, Values, and Variables.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html):

> 4.1. The Kinds of Types and Values
>
> There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types ([§4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)) and reference types ([§4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)). There are, correspondingly, two kinds of data values that can be stored in variables, passed as arguments, returned by methods, and operated on: primitive values ([§4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)) and reference values ([§4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)).
>
> 4.2. Primitive Types and Values
>
> A primitive type is predefined by the Java programming language and named by its reserved keyword ([§3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)):
>
> *PrimitiveType*:
>
> *{[Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-Annotation)} [NumericType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-NumericType)* 
> *{[Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-Annotation)} boolean*
>
> *NumericType*:
>
> [*IntegralType*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-IntegralType) 
> [*FloatingPointType*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-FloatingPointType)
>
> *IntegralType*:
> `byte` `short` `int` `long` `char`
>
> *FloatingPointType*:
> `float` `double`
>
> 4.3. Reference Types and Values
>
> There are four kinds of reference types: class types ([§8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)), interface types ([§9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1)), type variables ([§4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)), and array types ([§10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)).
>
> 4.3.1. Objects
>
> An object is a class instance or an *array*.
> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

So, an object is basically a variable which is not a primitive type. The primitive types are: byte, short, int, long, char, float, double and boolean. You should not confuse these primitive types with their class wrappers: Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Character, Float, Double and Boolean, respectively.

In case `Object` class doesn't define any method at all, then creating a class with no methods won't have any behavior at all, but in Java, by the definition of object, or a better term: **reference value**, is a variable that refers to an instance of a class or an array, which is basically any non-primitive type. Note that a reference value may not need any behavior **at all**, the behavior is defined in **the class**, and a reference value may use it or not.

Comment: It seems that underlying question here is:  Why Java needs primitives at all? Why Java creators did not make everything in Java an object?

I believe that it was done to achieve smaller memory footprint, more intuitive code and faster implementations.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't think that's the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

The example you showed is a Reference type vs a primitive type.  There are a few others, such as `char` vs. `Character` and `Long` vs `long`

The class variations of these primitives contain methods, fields and your other standard class-components. The primitives on the other hand are JUST the value. For example, if I wanted the string representation of a number.

3 has no methods. its a value. However, the class `Integer` has a `toString` method which prints its value. By creating an instance of `Integer` with the value 3 (`new Integer(3)`) you create a class and fill one of its fields.

This has its own uses, as does typing an argument or variable with `int`. This simply informs the interpreter that the value is of a certain type.

Comment: A String literal is an Object. You can do `synchronized("one")` but its a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

An object is like a snapshot of a class. So it can vary with time. In other words, it can vary in state and can behave differently with different state. An object can hold other objects too. In your example, nnn has a state but it shows no behavior

Comment: However, objects of the class `java.lang.Integer` do not have varying state, because they are immutable...

Comment: @Vwin That's not true. Immutable *by definition* means that you cannot change state/value. In your example, it is not the immutable object that is changing state. Changing objects != changing the objects' state.

Comment: I think you are correct, it doesn't change state rather point to a different location. Good!

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind is quite simple for Java. Object can be called instance of class that is derived from java.lang.Object class in its hierarchy.

In case of the primitives like char int or long the inheritance does not take place.

The consequence of that is that on any java object you are able to invoke method toString(). The key behind that is that you tell an object to perform some action. You can not tell a primitive to do something.

But however the concept of object is not defined by any language. This is more a paradigm aspect.