# Extending primitive types

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, primitive-types

**Is it possible to extend primitive types such as System.String and System.Int32 (IE: integer) in .Net 4 and if so how?**

To be more specific, I am aware of the concept of partial classes but this doesnt seem to be the answer. Also I find that System.String is not inheritable and Int32 is a structure.

Lastly I am interested in knowing both a VB.Net and C# answer to the above question.

Thanks all..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot extend them directly - the `String` class is sealed, for example, and as you noted value type wrappers (such as `Int32`) are normally structs.

You can write extension methods ([C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)) to them, that's what they are there for.

Another option, is to write a wrapper around these, exposing all of their properties and adding more functionality.

Comment: I didn't downvote, please explain how we can wrap String.

Comment: @Adrian - create a new class, put in a private `string` field (pass a `string` in to the contractor, assigning the passed in parameter to the field. Now you can write any wrapper functions you want - passing any to the string field as needed. You will not get compiler/language support for it as you do for strings, but that's how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Just as additional info (Oded is right already on the other stuff):

There are no "primitive types" in .Net. Only classes and value types (called structures in C#) (and all are decendents of object).

However you cannot inherit from value types (like int, byte, ...) and you cannot inherit from sealed classes (like string).

Comment: sry but that's inaccurate not all types derives from object
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx

Comment: I never wrote that ALL types derive from object. But classes and value types DO! Citation from YOUR linked page: "A great many types do derive from object. All value types, including enums and nullable types, derive from object."

Comment: You *did* write that all types derive from object by saying "Only classes and value types (called structures in C#) (and all are decendents of object)", and this is incorrect.  There are primitive types in .Net.  They map to structures, and they don't derive from object.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I don't think Foxfire was trying to say literally *all* types derive from `object`, but what he is saying is that classes and value types are descendants of `object`. 

- See this from Eric Lippert himself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1682604/7270462

> All C# types, including primitive types such as int and double, inherit from a single root object type.

- Also see this regarding value types being aliases:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

- Use the "Object Browser" in Visual Studio and find that the `System.ValueType` does indeed have `Object` as its base type.