# How is an "int" assigned to an object?

Tags: c#, .net, types

How are we able to assign an integer to an object in .NET?

Reference types are derived from System.Object and value types are from System.ValueType.

So, how is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [`System.ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx), it too derives from `System.Object`

Also see [How do ValueTypes derive from Object (ReferenceType) and still be ValueTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes)

Answer (score 22):

The term "boxing" is very opaque, but it is easy to visualize what is actually going on by using the debugger.  Write a little console mode application like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int value = 42;
            object obj = value;
        }  // <== Breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Set a breakpoint where indicated and press F5.  When the breakpoint hits, use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1.  In the Address box, type "obj".  You'll get a hex dump of the memory content of the object.  Right-click the window and select "4-byte Integer", the best way to visualize the object in this case.  You'll see something resembling this:

```
0x01CBF6BC  6e1a2d34 0000002a
```

The interesting parts here are 0x01CBF6BC, that's the address of the object on the garbage collected heap.  The next hex number, 6e1a2d34 is the so-called "type handle", also known as the "method table pointer".  That a 'cookie' that identifies the type of the object.  System.Int32 in this case.  Very important, it will be used later when the object is unboxed back to an Int32 to verify that the boxed value is actually an integer.

The next value you see, 0000002a, is the value of the boxed object.  You can use Windows calculator in programmer mode to convert back to decimal, it is 42.

Experiment with this, using different values and different types to see how it affects the boxed object.  You can modify the hex and see what effect it has on the obj value as displayed by the debugger.

The hex dump I gave you was for a 4 byte boxed value, boxing a double will take 8 bytes.  Boxing a struct will take more bytes.  There's also a part of the object header you can't see, the so-called syncblock, located at the address - 4.  Try the lock statement to see that changing.

Answer (score 14):

This is done by the process of `boxing` and `unboxing`. Please see following links for further reference:

[Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)
[Boxing and Unboxing of Value Types : What You Need to Know?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/stuart_fujitani/boxnunbox11192005055746am/boxnunbox.aspx)
[What is the difference between boxing/unboxing and type casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085144/what-is-the-difference-between-boxing-unboxing-and-type-casting)

Answer (score 7):

[Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from the object.

Answer (score 6):

You are [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the integer in an object.

That is, an object is created that *wraps* (or *boxes*) the integer. Kind of like putting something in a box in real life.

Comment: Boxing is a physical phenomenon. How does this actually happen (integer does not belong to System.Object) ?

Comment: dtb's quote from the same documentation sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method:

```
object ob;
int i=10;
ob=i;//(boxing)
int b;
b=(int)ob;//(unboxing)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in c# which should tell you they how/why.

This link has a great explanation and explains the reference vs value type question you are asking about:

http://www.dijksterhuis.org/exploring-boxing/

> Boxing is as simply putting a basic type in wrapper (making it a fully blown object), and unboxing taking that wrapped object and converts it back to a simpler type. To do the boxing managed memory needs to be allocated on the heap, references need to be updated, and the contents of the value type have to be copied.

Answer (score 1):

int in .NET has an underlying Integer type object and an implicit conversion.

Comment: I think you are confusing .NET with Java. And there isn't any implicit conversion going on; it's still an int, disguised as an object.

Comment: Oh yes I did.  That's what I get for not taking the time to think before posting.

Comment: @BoltClock Actually, due to odd circumstances, pwny is kind of right. The `int` type (and the other numeric types) in .net is a "magical" type: an `int` value, alone, is only 4 bytes, which means it cannot have RTTI. Only when you attempt to use it as an object (such as when boxed) is it put inside a `System.Integer` instance, which is only a wrapper. If you look at the `System.Integer` class through Reflector, you'll see that its sole member is `int m_value`. So there _is_ an implicit conversion going on, the only thing is that it happens at a lower level than what one could expect.

Comment: @BoltClock Or at least, that's what I was told when I asked how come `System.Integer` contains an `int`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375165/system-int32-contains-another-system-int32

Answer (score 0):

System.ValueType is also derived from System.Object, so that is why:

See inheritance hierarchy here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx