# .NET behind the scenes: What does 'object' store?

Tags: .net, clr

A naïve type system would store objects as a pointer to its type (which contains lots of useful information, like a vtable, object size, etc.) followed by its data. If .Net had such a type system an `object` would take up 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, and 8 bytes on 64-bit.

[We can see that it doesn't](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx). The object overhead is two pointer-sizes, plus, there's a 'minimum' size of one more pointer-size.

So what does `object` actually store in it, behind the scenes?

Comment: Even better [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's what it looks like.  The 'type handle', aka 'method table pointer' is at offset 0, the object data follows at offset 4.  There's an extra field at offset-4 named the 'syncblock'.  It is there because it also participates in the garbage collected heap when the object space is not in use, a double-linked list of free blocks that requires two pointers.  Not letting that going to waste, the syncblock has several uses like storing the lock state, storing the hash code, storing a pointer to an explicit syncblock when too much needs to be stored.

The smallest possible object is for a boxed byte, 4 + 4 + 1 = 9 bytes.  But allocation granularity for the GC heap is 4 bytes so you'll get the next multiple of 4, 12 bytes.

This is all pretty visible with the debugger in Visual Studio.  You'll find hints in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383074/how-is-an-int-assigned-to-an-object/5383926#5383926).

Comment: So a boxed `byte` is actually smaller than `new object()`?

Comment: A plain object is still 12 bytes with the 4 extra bytes always set to 0.

Answer (score 5):

(This is all from the [Microsoft Shared Source CLI](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=3A1C93FA-7462-47D0-8E56-8DD34C6292F0&displaylang=en); it has the source code of the CLR.)

If you take a look at `clr\src\vm\object.h`, you will see:

```
// The generational GC requires that every object be at least 12 bytes in size.
#define MIN_OBJECT_SIZE     (2*sizeof(BYTE*) + sizeof(ObjHeader))
```

which is pretty self-explanatory. Furthermore, in `clr\src\vm\gcscan.cpp`, you can see statements such as

```
_ASSERTE(g_pObjectClass->GetBaseSize() == MIN_OBJECT_SIZE);
```

or

```
_ASSERTE(totalSize < totalSize + MIN_OBJECT_SIZE);
```

which I think explains why you're seeing the unexpected object sizes. :)

---

**Update:**

@Hans had a great point on the sync block; I just want to point out a subtlety, documented again in `object.h`:

```
/* Object
 *
 * This is the underlying base on which objects are built. The MethodTable
 * pointer and the sync block index live here. The sync block index is actually
 * at a negative offset to the instance. See syncblk.h for details.
 */

class Object
{
    protected:
        MethodTable*    m_pMethTab;
    //No other fields shown here!
};
```

Notice this part:

> The sync block index is actually at a ***negative offset*** to the instance.

So the sync block apparently doesn't actually *follow* the method table (as Hans mentioned), but it comes *before* it -- so it's not a "normal" part of the object (for the lack of a better word).