# Why C# builtin types contain implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, roslyn

It's a known fact builtin types like Int32/Double/... are implemented on compiler level, and users cannot implement recursive structs like `Int32`:

```
public readonly struct Int32 : IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>, ISpanFormattable
{
    private readonly int m_value; // Do not rename (binary serialization)
```

Considering `int` to be an alias to `Int32` we have an unsolvable recursion here. But it's fine since it get compiler's "special comprehension".

However, I wonder why it contains any implementation at all. If you look at [the file](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Int32.cs) you can see that there is code that real runtime seems to actually use.

I wonder why bultin types are not just stubs? I firstly imagined that it may be used as implementation of the boxed value, but it doesn't work to me since it's declared as `struct`. However, with compiler black magic everything becomes possible. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: The actual built-in (primitive) types are _mapped_ to the library types. They are not 'implemented' by them.

Comment: What kind of problem do you see here?

Comment: @bommelding ECMA334/335 treat them as aliases so they are precisely the same thing

Comment: My concern is that you can't write `struct MyInt32 { private MyInt32 m_value; }`, but compiler do it here since `typeof(int) == typeof(Int32)`

Comment: I would indeed write that off as compiler magic. In general, you can't create a primitive type.

Comment: It seems like a smart design to do that. Runtime magic is always more work and more brittle. Write as much code in C# as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Int32 contains... another System.Int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375165/system-int32-contains-another-system-int32)