# .NET C# : Does System.Int64 have a base type of System.ValueType?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, inheritance, types, structure

When looking at mscorlib.dll via Object Browser in Visual Studio 2008, the IDE indicates that Int64 (as well as the other data types) has a base type of ValueType.

In C#, I am aware that structs (which Int64 is) do not support object inheritance.  I even checked the type metadata of an assembly in which I declared a System.Int64 property of a class, and there was no indication of Int64 extending any classes.  Structs can extend interfaces, and I am aware of this.

I am confused on why the struct Int64 is showing a BaseType of ValueType.

Could someone please explain?

d[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All value types implicitly inherit `System.ValueType`.

Comment: I thought structs couldn't inherit from anything other than System.Object?  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(VS.71).aspx )

Comment: @contactmatt: Take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes/1682604#1682604

Comment: @LukeH - So the above MSDN documentation is wrong?  As taken from the above MSDN link: "There is no inheritance for structs as there is for classes. A struct cannot inherit from another struct or class, and it cannot be the base of a class. Structs, however, inherit from the base class Object."

Comment: @contactmatt: See the newer documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx  `All value types are derived implicitly from the System.ValueType.`

Comment: @contactmatt: The distinction is enforced automatically by the compiler. MSDN is more than likely telling you that you cannot specify that a struct inherit from any arbitrary class.

Comment: @Cody Gray - Alright, so the .NET compiler forces the type inheritance, but I cannot (as I tested by the compiler) tell the struct to inherit anything but an interface.  I think I got it.