# C# Boxing of valuetypes. Questions on size and type of boxing wrappers and valuetypes

Tags: .net

After reading [ValueTypes - RefTypes - EricLippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes) I have 3 questions:

Because say an 'int' derives from System.ValueType which derives from System.Object,

So how much space really does the value type like 'int' take (seeing that it finally derives from System.Object) ? 
Is it only size of int or the extra CLR bookkeeping fields used to distinguish it being value type.

Size difference between 'int' and 'object' ?

When 'int' is boxed with a wrapper. so is it the case that the wrapper is just an object type (and *that* object goes to heap) ? difference between this wrapper object and plain new object() ? how much size/space does that wrapper result to ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `int` is 32 bits, no matter what, because it's a *value*.

The `Object` part only comes into play once you box it (for example in C# cast it to an `object`). Once that happens, a new object is created with everything an object has, and inside that object resides your int.

This is why C# generics are so amazing, compared to say Java, because you don't force value types into objects just to put them in a generic container, so value types are actually value types the whole time (or until the programmer gets lazy and starts throwing `object val=...` around).

Edit: I can understand the confusion, because of how amazing a job they did with the compiler:

```
var s=12.GetType(); // if it looks like an object and walks like an object...
```

But it is *not* an object, not until the `GetType` call, at which point the value gets boxed into an object and you invoke the virtual method on it.

It's the same with `ValueType` being derived from `Object`. Just some pretty syntactic sugar the compiler ignores and does weird things behind your back :)

edit2: Here's the dissasembled code showing the boxing:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.Type s)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.s 12
    L_0003: box int32          // <---
    L_0008: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
    L_000d: stloc.0 
    L_000e: ldloc.0 
    L_000f: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    L_0014: nop 
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

Comment: so for every such method call (methods in System.Object) will result into temporary boxing ? I read in one of related threads where Marc Gravell says (and shows with IL) that boxing will happen only for not-overriden methods of System.Object.

Comment: If you mean non-virtual, it's exactly the opposite. It's the need of a virtual table that forces boxing, because the compiler needs to know what functions to call at run-time. Of course, the compiler could step in and work some of its magic, but I'm fairly certain calling `ToString` for instance results in boxing.

Comment: ok +1 for general concept ! and answering to 1 related part of the question. i am also looking for answer to wrapper related part. thanks.

Comment: I already mentioned that the wrapper contains your integer, so it's the size of an object plus your 32 bit integer. Since has no state besides the virtual table, the whole thing is 8 bytes on a 32-bit system and 12 bytes on a 64-bit system.

Comment: What about the state used to distinguish between reftype and valuetype , some flag must be there. Or is everything decided at compile time and code generated accordingly (and no need of run-time distinction) ?

Comment: It's distinguished by a field in the function signature. The JIT'er uses the information, but once it's used it can most likely be ignored so it won't be part of the final object (although it can be accessed by reflection any time you want).