# Are structs and enums really Objects, or are they just convertible to Objects?

Tags: c#, .net

From the MSDN:

> In cases where it is necessary for a value type to behave like an
>   object, a wrapper that makes the value type look like a reference
>   object is allocated on the heap, and the value type's value is copied
>   into it. The wrapper is marked so the system knows that it contains a
>   value type. This process is known as boxing, and the reverse process
>   is known as unboxing. Boxing and unboxing allow any type to be treated
>   as an object.

It seems to me that value types are treated completely different from reference types, even though they inherit from a reference type (both Object and ValueType). Am I right?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841562/414076 . You might find the bit below the second block-quote particularly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, YES.

That is how it is defined by the specifications!

> C# has a unified type system. All C# types, including primitive types
>   such as int and double, inherit from a single root object type. Thus,
>   all types share a set of common operations, and values of any type can
>   be stored, transported, and operated upon in a consistent manner.
>   Furthermore, C# supports both user-defined reference types and value
>   types, allowing dynamic allocation of objects as well as in-line
>   storage of lightweight structures.

Are they implemented differently?  Yes, but they are still `System.Object`s.

Anywhere in the specifications, in which they refer to `object`s or `System.Objects`, you can be quite certain that it refers to all types.

What would you expect as the output for the following code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflowConsole
{
   public class EmptyClass
   {
   }

   public class ReferenceStuff : EmptyClass
   {
      object a;
   }

   public class TypeStuff : EmptyClass
   {
      int a;
   }

   class Test
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         ReferenceStuff r = new ReferenceStuff();
         TypeStuff t = new TypeStuff();

         if (r is EmptyClass)
         {
           Console.WriteLine("r is an EmptyClass");
         }
         if (t is EmptyClass)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("t is an EmptyClass");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Not surprisingly, the output is:

```
r is an EmptyClass
t is an EmptyClass
```

Why?  Because they are both `EmptyClass` objects.  `EmptyClass` doesn't contribute anything that `object` doesn't, but both r and t are of type `EmptyClass` nonetheless.