# How / Why possible a value type derives from a reference type?

Tags: c#, .net, types, value-type, reference-type

In `.NET`, all value types inherit from the class named [System.ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx). `System.ValueType` is a class, so it is a `reference type`.

My question is how and why possible a `value type` derives from a `reference type`?

Comment: There are some special types in the type system which are unlike any ones you can write yourself. They don't necessarily follow the same rules that you have to.

Comment: Largely, it comes down to definitions... anything **that inherits from** `System.ValueType` is **defined** to be a `struct`, so get different treatment. As for why: so you can cast to `object` / `ValueType` (but: this is a boxing conversion).

Comment: @MarcGravell `System.Enum` is a class, a reference type, not a struct, but inherits from `ValueType`

Comment: @hvd true; an exception there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do ValueTypes derive from Object (ReferenceType) and still be ValueTypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is the key paragraph in the documentation

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you
>   cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead,
>   individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as
>   struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support
>   the creation of value types.

The inheritance occurs when the compiler compiles the overriden virtual methods of `System.Object`. The `System.ValueType` class simply provides more appropriate overloads of `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()` etc. As the document states the compiler uses these overloads if the `struct` keyword is used (in C#). This tells the compiler use the `System.ValueType` methods instead of the `System.Object` methods.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it still uses the `System.Object` methods; but: it does them as a `constrained`+`callvirt` call (rather than just a `callvirt`)

Comment: @MarcGravell - I don't doubt you, but why then does the documentation say `ValueType overrides the virtual methods from Object with more appropriate implementations for value types`? Can you provide a link that explains what you are saying please.

Comment: @Tobsey: The default implementations of `Equals` and `HashCode` assume that `X.Equals(Y)` will only return true if `X` and `Y` refer to the same heap object instance.  Such an implementation would be meaningless with value types, since `5.Equals(5)` would cause two distinct object instances, both holding the value 5, to be compared against each other.  Thus, `ValueType` overrides `Equals` so that by default it regards things as equal if corresponding fields match.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible because being a value type or reference type is not inherited. The same applies to [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx). The class itself is a reference type, but enums are value types.

Answer (score 1):

A possibly easier example is that all value types derive from `System.Object`, which is a reference type too.

```
int i = 3;
int j = 3;
object io = i;
object jo = j;
```

At this point, `io` and `jo` are references that refer to a copy of the values of `i` and `j`. The values can be extracted again using a cast:

```
int i2 = (int)io;
int j2 = (int)jo;
```

Functionally, this works roughly as if the conversion to `object` creates a `class ValueWrapper<T> { public T value; }` object behind the scenes, and `io` is set to `new ValueWrapper<int> { value = i }`. The cast from `io` to `int` then reads `((ValueWrapper<int>)io).value`.

This is not exactly what happens, but what does happen is similar enough that this hopefully clarifies sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

[Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/) says in [The C# Programming Language 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765):

> This point is frequently confusing to novices. I am often asked, “But
>   how is it possible that a value type derives from a reference type?” I
>   think the confusion arises as a result of a misunderstanding of what
>   “derives from” means. Derivation does not imply that the layout of the
>   bits in memory of the base type is somewhere found in the layout of
>   bits in the derived type. Rather, it simply implies that some
>   mechanism exists whereby members of the base type may be accessed from
>   the derived type.

Comment: What a Great Idea to mark an answer with 0 reputation answered by yourself when Answer with 5 reputation is Present.Only to Earn Point ?