# Value type and Reference Type

Tags: c#, .net

I am a little confused about few statements in C# reference.

1. `Object` is a reference type
2. `Struct` is Value type
3. `Struct` is derived from Object Class

Why shouldn't struct or any other value type also be a reference type in this case.

correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564090/how-why-possible-a-value-type-derives-from-a-reference-type

Comment: This topic has been discussed many times over the years. I am surprised you have not been able to find any of those discussions.

Comment: Check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606778/4156229) the example is given in java but it might help

Answer (score 0):

Because it is part of the spec. So, the compiler team is forcing this. I believe there is an article that talks about this being an implementation detail, but cannot find it currently.

You might want to take a look at [Struct/Heap Storage question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815354/why-are-structs-stored-on-the-stack-while-classes-get-stored-on-the-heap-net), also. It probably will help clear some things up.

Answer (score 0):

It is because that Struct is a special case, and CLR work with it in special manner.