# Arrays of ReferenceType and ValueType are invalid argument of an object array

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to call the following function :

```
static string GetValueOrDefault(object[] values, int index)
{
    if (values == null)
         return string.Empty;
    if (index >= values.Length)
         return string.Empty;
    return values[index] != null ? values[index].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

When I call GetValueOrDefault with an array of strings (ReferenceType), it works :

```
GetValueOrDefault(new[] {"foo", "bar"}, 0);
```

When I call GetValueOrDefault with an array of int (ValueType), it doesn't work :

```
GetValueOrDefault(new[] {1, 2}, 0);
```

The compiler error is :

> The best overloaded method match for
>   MyNamespace.GetValueOrDefault(object[], int)' has some invalid
>   arguments

So my question is : Why this doesn't compile as [reference types and value type derive from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes) ?

I know I can solve this problem using generics, but I want to understand this error

```
static string GetValueOrDefault<T>(T[] values, int index)
{...}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault(new object[] { 1, 2 }, 0);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays of reference-types are covariant, meaning: a `string[]` can be treated as an `object[]` (although the gotcha is that if you try to put a non-string in, it will `throw`). However, arrays of value-types are *not* covariant, so an `int[]` ***cannot*** be treated as an `object[]`. `new[] {1,2}` is an `int[]`.

IIRC this was done mainly for similarity with java. The covariance in .NET 4.0 is much tidier.

Comment: Very interesting, didn't know that was the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've just found an Eric's article speaking about that : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx