# Is a struct just a class that derives from ValueType?

Tags: c#

Is it true to say that a struct is just a class which inherits from System.ValueType?

Is the keyword "struct" just syntactic sugar for writing a class with : System.ValueType after the name?

If it is just a class, then is it true to say that not all classes are reference types since structs are technically classes?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes

Comment: I think that there are 2 meanings of "class" which you may be mixing in your question "class as name of particular set of Type as defined by C#" and "class as equivalent of type in general CS sense". In C# `class` and `struct` specify distinct sets of "classes".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite "just syntactical sugar".  From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx):

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you
>   cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead,
>   individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as
>   struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support
>   the creation of value types.

So *could* you say that a `struct` is just a `class` that inherits from `System.ValueType` *semantically*?  That'd debatable.  All `struct` are derived from `System.ValueType`, but you can't explicitly create a `class` that derives from `System.ValueType`.

In addition, of course, just being derived from `System.ValueType`, `struct` has a lot of differences from `class` as you probably know.  But if not, I have a blog post on some of the key differences [here](http://www.blackrabbitcoder.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/29/c-fundamentals-the-differences-between-struct-and-class.aspx), including but not limited to:

- Value types are, of course, passed and assigned by value, not by reference.
- A `struct` cannot accept initialization values for their fields in the definition (they always given values for their declared field types).
- A `struct` can have events, but since they are value types must take care that you aren't subscribing to a copy!
- You cannot inherit from a `struct`.
- You cannot create `struct` parameterless constructor, `struct` provides one which cannot be overridden.
- Creating an overloaded `struct` constructor does not hide the parameterless constructor.
- The `this` keyword, used in a `struct` is a value variable, not a reference.
- You do not need to use `new` to create an instance of a `struct` (but if you do this you must provide a value for all fields before it is used.

MSDN also has some good advice on when to use `struct` vs `class`.  Because they are value types, you should think of them as such and limit them to smaller things (16 bytes or less) and preferably as immutable representations of a single value (like `DateTime`, `TimeStamp` etc.).

Comment: why should you limit value types to 16 bytes?

Comment: @user2063755- Most likely I think their recommendation is at 16 bytes because once you get larger than that, the overall cost (mem & time) of copying the value type would exceed the overall cost of the reference counting.

Answer (score 5):

### [Class and struct differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Structs differ from classes in several important ways:

- Structs are value types (Section 11.3.1).
- All struct types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType (Section 11.3.2).
- Assignment to a variable of a struct type creates a copy of the value being assigned (Section 11.3.3).
- The default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null (Section 11.3.4).
- Boxing and unboxing operations are used to convert between a struct type and object (Section 11.3.5).
- The meaning of this is different for structs (Section 11.3.6).
- Instance field declarations for a struct are not permitted to include variable initializers (Section 11.3.7).
- A struct is not permitted to declare a parameterless instance constructor (Section 11.3.8).
- A struct is not permitted to declare a destructor (Section 11.3.9).

See also: [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)