# Struct is value type while it's derived from Object class - how it works in .Net framework

Tags: c#, .net, clr, value-type, reference-type

As we all know that everything in C# is derived from Object class.

Then why struct is value type and class is reference type? I mean struct (type) itself has derived from Object class (class type) then how we can say that struct is not a reference type?

Comment: There is a bunch of differences between `struct`s and `class'es. The fact they both inherit from `object` does not matter here. It's a design choice to have a common type for both ref and value types, but it also introduces some additional complexity to the language, like boxing. You should also look into `ValueType` class which is a base class for all value types in .NET.

Comment: IMHO this question is NOT a duplicate. As the referenced "original" question does not elaborate at all as to how it can be that deriving from a **class** Object yields a **structure**.

Comment: MarcinJurasek Please read the question carefully before reaching to any conclusion :)

Comment: While I agree that it is ***close***, I don't think that this is actually a duplicate.  That said, it may also not be a good fit for SO since the answer may be too broad or too opinionated, unless one of language designers/developers can chime in, since only they can say WHY the decision was made.

Comment: It's NOT a duplicate of the marked question, and is a pretty fair question IMHO.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes is closer to what one would call as duplicate. Hope now OP gets the answer he's looking for.