# How to convert any int into any generic Enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

Because Enums aren't guaranteed to be of type int...

```
public enum ExampleEnum : int / ulong / whatever
```

You cannot do this with enums:

```
int i = (int)exampleEnum;
```

However in my case, while I don't know the exact 'type of enum' being used, I can guarantee that it will be a "int type" of enum.

So I can do this:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(exampleEnum);
```

Cool. **Here's the problem**: I don't know of a way to do the inverse (which I need to do), as:

```
Enum exampleEnum = (Enum)exampleEnum;
```

has error:

> Cannot cast expression of type 'int' to type 'Enum'

And I cannot find an inverse of Convert.ToInt32(Enum enum)

---

That is the question, if you think more detail on what I'm trying to do is useful, I can provide you with it. But in a nutshell I am creating a generic GUI method that takes in any type of Enum:

```
public static int EditorPrefEnumField(string label, Enum defaultValue, string editorPrefString)
```

and getting it to work (the way I want) involves converting the Enum to and from an int.

Comment: `MyEnum exampleEnum = (MyEnum)5;` ?

Comment: `Enum` is a class that is the base for all `enum` types. It's a special type, similar to `ValueType`. You need to cast as the specific type you want rather than just as `Enum`, as demonstrated in the comment above.

Comment: This is a Unity question in disguise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enum.ToObject()` method. You need to specify the actual `enum type` for that. Here is a generic method to encapsulate `Enum.ToObject()`

```
public enum TestEnum : int 
{
    A=1, B=2, C=3
};

public T GetEnumFromInt<T>(int value) where T : Enum
{
    return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Enum value = GetEnumFromInt<TestEnum>(2);
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString()); // Displays "B" 
}
```

You need to specify the concrete type of `Enum` you want because `Enum` is an abstract type and one cannot create instances of abstract types.

Comment: This is correct! This is basically the code I ended up using:
'Enum exampleEnum = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, intValue);'

Answer (score 0):

Take this code where I store an error code as an `Int`:

```
public class CommonError
{
   public int Code { get; set; }

   public CommonError FromErrorCode(Enum code, string description = "")
   {
        Code = (int)Enum.Parse(code.GetType(), code.ToString());                        
        return this;
   }
}
```

Yet what I'm doing when I call it is parsing in different Enums:

```
new CommonError().FromErrorCode((int)GeneralErrorCodes.SYSTEM_BASE_ERROR);
```

> Cool. Here's the problem: I don't know of a way to do the inverse (which I need to do)

To do the reverse of this you need the Enum Type, eg:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(AnEmumType))

Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnEmumType)).ToList();
```